# Outlook 2016 – Sent Items Consolidation Search

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a personal Outlook 2016 account and am Owner/Member of two Group mailbox accounts. Is there a way to consolidate my sent items from all three mailboxes to one sent items folder while retaining the different from addresses on the outgoing email?  Or search all three Sent Item folders, and only those three folders, with one query?

Comment: Outlook allows virtual folders built from queries. This would be the simplest way to do this, and each message would still only actually exist in the original Sent folder.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Unfortunately, the Outlook virtual folders Custom Search option only allows <Select Folder(s)> by folder tree check box from the primary account, not the other two group mailboxes (accounts) that am Owner/Member of. (sigh)

Comment: What do you mean by Group mailbox accounts? Shared accounts in Outlook client?

Comment: Three Outlook accounts where illustrative email addresses are:
my.name@company.com Microsoft Exchange (set send from this account by default)
department.a@company.com Microsoft Exchange
department.b@company.com   Microsoft Exchange

Comment: For the two departmental email addresses, I am the Owner and can add/del/mod Members from Access Control Lists = ACL-department.a & ACL-department.b via the Corporate Address Book.  
Members of the departmental accounts can all access the respective account mailbox inboxes to provide redundant group coverage and respond to incoming email so there is no single point of failure to respond during absences. Also team coverage helps where one member may not have the knowledge to respond, but multiple members means responses are spread out to more knowledge resources.

Comment: The issue is:
Responding to my.name inbox email puts the replies in my.name Sent Items folder
Responding to department.a inbox email puts the replies in departmant.a Sent Items folder 
Responding to department.b inbox email puts the replies in departmant.b Sent Items folder     
I need to search all three Sent Items folders, and only those three folders, with one query.